# dataframe new column based on groupby operations

Tags: python, dataframe

```
import pandas
import numpy

df = pandas.DataFrame({'id_1' : [1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2], 
                      'id_2' :  [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                      'v_1' :   [2,1,1,3,2,1,2,4,1,1,2],
                      'v_2' :   [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2],
                      'v_3' :   [3,3,3,3,4,4,4,3,3,3,3]})


In [4]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[4]: 
    id_1  id_2  v_1  v_2  v_3
0      1     1    2    1    3
1      2     1    1    1    3
2      1     1    1    1    3
3      1     1    3    1    3
4      1     1    2    2    4
5      1     2    1    2    4
6      1     2    2    2    4
7      2     2    4    1    3
8      2     2    1    1    3
9      2     2    1    2    3
10     2     2    2    2    3

sub = df[(df['id_1'] == 1) & (df['id_2'] == 1)].copy()
sub['v_4'] = numpy.where(sub['v_1'] == sub['v_2'].shift(), 'A', \
                         numpy.where(sub['v_1'] == sub['v_3'].shift(), 'B', 'C'))


In [6]: sub                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[6]: 
   id_1  id_2  v_1  v_2  v_3 v_4
0     1     1    2    1    3   C
2     1     1    1    1    3   A
3     1     1    3    1    3   B
4     1     1    2    2    4   C
```

I have a dataframe as defined above. I would like to perform some operation, basically categorize whether v_1 equals the previous v_2 or v_3 for each group of (id_1, id_2)
I have done the the operation which performs on a sub df. And I would like to have a one line code to combine the following groupby together with the operation I have on the sub df together.

```
gbdf = df.groupby(by=['id_1', 'id_2'])
```

I have tried something like

```
gbdf['v_4'] = numpy.where(gbdf['v_1'] == gbdf['v_2'].shift(), 'A', \
                         numpy.where(gbdf['v_1'] == gbdf['v_3'].shift(), 'B', 'C'))
```

and the error was

```
'DataFrameGroupBy' object does not support item assignment
```

I also tried

```
df['v_4'] = numpy.where(gbdf['v_1'] == gbdf['v_2'].shift(), 'A', \
                         numpy.where(gbdf['v_1'] == gbdf['v_3'].shift(), 'B', 'C'))
```

which I believe the result was wrong, it does not align the groupby result with the original ordering.

I am wondering whether there is an elegant way to achieve this.

Comment: `a one line code` - why does it need to be one line?

Comment: @wwii it does not need to be one line, I just want it to be clear and easy to understand. Obviously I can do a for loop iterate thru all the combination of id_1 and id_2 then concat all the result sub df together to get the big one. But I am wondering whether there is any way to do it cleaner.

Comment: Am I correctly understanding you'd like to add a `v_4` column to each of the groups in `gbdf`? So that the first table in `gbdf` is basically the same as `sub` and the others follow the same pattern for the rest of the groups?

Comment: @Grismar yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets you a list of dataframes that match the content of the dataframe `sub`, but for all results of the `.groupby()`:

```
import numpy
import pandas

source = pandas.DataFrame(
    {'id_1': [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
     'id_2': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
     'v_1': [2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2],
     'v_2': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2],
     'v_3': [3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3]})


def add_v4(df):
    df['v_4'] = numpy.where(df['v_1'] == df['v_2'].shift(), 'A', numpy.where(df['v_1'] == df['v_3'].shift(), 'B', 'C'))
    return df


dfs = [add_v4(pandas.DataFrame(slice)) for _, slice in source.groupby(by=['id_1', 'id_2'])]
print(dfs)
```

About this line:

```
dfs = [add_v4(pandas.DataFrame(slice)) for _, slice in source.groupby(by=['id_1', 'id_2'])]
```

It's a list comprehension that gets all the slices from the `groupby` and turns them into actual new dataframes before passing them to `add_v4`, which returns the modified dataframe to be added to the list.

Comment: Thanks, this is essentially doing it sequentially for each 'sub' df, right?  I am wondering where by NOT using for loop, it will take advantage of vector operations. The original dataframe is fairly large.

Comment: It's not using a "for loop" per se, but it *will* perform the column addition once per subgroup. However, since you opted to group information using `groupby`, it seems to me that you need to perform the operation once per group regardless - the only main difference I'd look into is whether you need the data in separate dataframes, or all in the original df.